# What is efficient and stable external sort algorithm implementation (written in c)?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, external-sorting

What is efficient and stable external sort algorithm implementation (written in c)?

Comment: With "external", do you mean "anything not `qsort`"?

Comment: any external sorting algorithms implemented in C

Comment: It seems that "external sorting" is a kind of algorithm that can handle massive amount of data. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Look at implementing an external merge-sort.  You can see sample C++ (other than the example's use of file streams essentially C) along with information on the algorithm [here](http://cis.stvincent.edu/html/tutorials/swd/extsort/extsort.html).

Answer (score 0):

Unix `sort` is extremely efficient, and it's exactly what you're looking for. You may want to have a look at its algorithmic details [here](http://vkundeti.blogspot.com/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html).

Comment: Unfortunately no it is not, and it is not configurable enough to be general useable.